# Are these narrations of Ibn as-Sunni authentic?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, dhikr

I have searched everywhere on the internet and I can not find any information about these following narrations that I will show. They are from the book "**Kitab al-Adhkar**" from Imam An-Nawawi, and there are no commentaries or authentications even in the book for these ahadith.

I find it very interesting and because I could not find anything throughout my research, I wanted to ask for these following narrations if they are authentic or not, since I do not want to act upon something I have no knowledge of:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

<sup>The red box is a narration which was not referenced at all, only the Qur'an Verse has been mentioned, still it states that it was narrated from al-Khudri</sup>

---

Comment: i assume this kitab al-adhkar is written by imam nawawi.he is a credible source and a very esteemed author who has many other religious work written, so its highly probable that he would include only the authentic. the first picture you have posted, there is a similar hadith in sahih muslim (1908) with a very similar wording.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem imam an-Nawawi in Kitab al-Adhkar has chosen to compile ahadith from ibn as-Sunni's book instead of those of his teacher an-Nasa-i (both had books on adhkaar) this is a known criticism many scholars made about his book. An-Nawawi made this book as short and easy as possible this however made it rather less satisfactory to specialists as the qualification of ahadith therein is rather lenient. This however shouldn't be a huge issue as long as he didn't declare very weak ahadith or fabrications as only weak.

Comment: @Medi1Saif thank you for the insight as this is new information for me regarding compilation of this book.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem there are enough weak or even certain munkar ahadith included that is why I am asking for the authenticity

Comment: @Medi1Saif I do not know if they are daif jiddan, munkar or maudu which is why I would like to know the authenticity of those narrations because I do not want to act on something I have no knowledge of

Comment: I strongly recommend you to ask about each of them one by one, as this could produce a lengthy post.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So, should I post for every picture one question, and when it is anwsered, then again? Or how should I do it? Does not really look convenient either. I mean, my thread here is already a long one, basically expects a long reply which would be fine imo...

Comment: That is the best way to cover a single narration entirely. Else you can hardly expect an answer!