# Are these narrations of Ibn as-Sunni authentic? (Last part)

Tags: hadith, dua, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, dhikr

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

<sup>Following the suggestion from @Medi1Saif regarding this [post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71846/are-these-narrations-of-ibn-as-sunni-authentic). Hereinafter, these adhkar (in parts) are taken from the book of Imam An-Nawawi, which have no mention of any commentary or authentication. Furthermore, throughout my research on the internet, I have not found any information regarding these ahadith of Ibn as-Sunni.</sup>

---

<sup><sup>- Here are the [first](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72026/are-these-narrations-of-ibn-as-sunni-authentic-part-1) and [second](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72045/are-these-narrations-of-ibn-as-sunni-authentic-part-2) part -</sup></sup>

Comment: It's the first time I read/hear of the first du'a, as for the second the beginning is mentioned in more authentic sources the third is familiar, however I might have seen/read randomly a negative qualification of it somewhere, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Subhanallah, there is always something new that can be learned or discovered which increases the interest. But all ahadith that I show here are from the book of Imam An-Nawawi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll mainly follow the same procedure as described in [Are these narrations of Ibn as-Sunni authentic? (Part 2)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72045/are-these-narrations-of-ibn-as-sunni-authentic-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and applied in [Are these narrations of Ibn as-Sunni authentic? (Part 1)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72026/are-these-narrations-of-ibn-as-sunni-authentic-part-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Note this is a work in progress:

### Analysis of the du'a: Alhamdu Li-Llahi al-Ladhi wahaba lana hada al-Yawm ...

**Hadith including the full narrator chain in ibn as-Sunni's book**

> 148 - أخبرني محمد بن علي، حدثنا بشر بن موسى، حدثنا يحيى بن إسحاق السيلحيني، حدثنا مهدي بن ميمون، عن واصل الأحدب، عن أبي وائل، أن **عبد الله بن مسعود**، رضي الله عنه قال: يا جارية، انظري هل طلعت الشمس؟ فقالت: لا. ثم واصل فسبح، فقال لها ثانية: انظري هل طلعت الشمس؟ فقالت: لا. ثم قال لها الثالثة: طلعت الشمس؟ قالت: نعم. قال: "الحمد لله الذي وهب لنا هذا اليوم، وأقالنا فيه عثراتنا. قال مهدي: وأحسبه قال: ولم يعذبنا بالنار " *موقوف* ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13132/278#p1))
> I was informed by Muhammad ibn 'Ali, from Bishr ibn Musa, from Yahya ibn Ishaaq as-Saylahyny, from Mahdi ibn Maymoon, From Waasil al-Ahdab, from abu Wa'il that **'Abdullah ibn Mas'ud** may Allah be pleased with him said: O Handmaid, look, is the sun out? She said: No. Then he continued and did tasbeeh, and said to her again: Look, has the sun risen? She said: No. Then he said to her for the third time: Has the sun risen? She said: Yes. He said:" Praise be to Allah, Who has granted us this day and has waived our offences. Al-Mahdi said: "And I think he said: He did not torment us with fire". *Mawqoof*.

A mawqoof hadith basically is a practice or statement of a sahabi () it could be regarded as stronger than a da'if hadith if it was identified as authentic.

Note that the indication of the teacher (Muhammad ibn 'Ali) of ibn as-Sunni at least gives six possible results -most of them are rather unknown narrators- in [the database](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/10233/%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AD) I've often consult. While a-Dhahabi only pointed at a student with this name in his Siyar.

- Ahmad ibn Muhammad ibn 'Ali ibn Bahr أحمد بن محمد بن علي (unknown)
- Muhammad ibn 'Ali  al-Antaki محمد بن علي بن حمزة بن صابح (Died323 a.H., sadooq)
- Muhammad ibn 'Ali al-Kufi محمد بن علي بن مهدي بن زياد (sadooq, hassan al-Hadith)
- Muhammad ibn 'Ali محمد بن علي بن عبد الله (unknown)
- Muhammad ibn 'Ali al-Qutbi محمد بن علي (unknown)
- Muhammad ibn 'Ali al-Bazzar محمد بن علي بن بحر بن بري (died 294 a.H., also unknown)

**Some scholarly qualification and analysis**

An-Nawawi in his Adhkar only reported a paraphrased summary of the hadith with the du'a without any qualification (see here [#242](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1956/87)). Al-Arnaoot also remained silent about it too.

Ibn Hajar in his Natai'j al-Afkar volume 2 page 440 addressed the surrounding story of the hadith with his own narrator chain which correlates with the part from Bishr ibn Musa to ibn Mas'ood (only ibn as-Sunni's teacher is not included) and declared the sanad as sahih. Here's a copy of the content:
[image]

The only differences between the two are the remaining narrators and the additional details in the narration of ibn Hajar: abu Wa'il apparently didn't come alone, and added the information that he came after the fajr and shortly before a-Shuruq and it includes a missing part of the story as narrated by ibn as-Sunni, that ibn Masu'd after receiving his guests already had started doing tasbih (in ibn as-Sunni's narration it is said - later- he continued doing it) then he started asking his home maid...

This means that the hadith is marfo' and a doing or saying of a sahabi and as is it is fine to do accordingly as the value of a sahih narrative from a Sahabi is better or equal a da'if hadith.

Further the hadith appears in Sahih ibn Hebban [#2607](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/5238) with a slight difference in the wording and some additions. This version correlates with the narrator chain of ibn as-Sunni from Mahdi ibn Maymoon to ibn Mas'od and has narrators of Sahih Muslim as stated in the comments. In another copy the commentator says that except with Shayban ibn Farukh شيبان بن فروخ who's a narrator of imam Muslim's Sahih it would fit the conditions of al-Bukhari too -see the hadith [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/3837#p1) and the comment in the next page-. The addition is the following conversation between ibn Mas'ood and one of his visitors:

> قال: فقال رجل من القوم: قرأت المفصل البارحة كله، قال عبد الله: هذا كهذ الشعر، «إني لأحفظ القرائن التي كان يقرؤهن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ثمانية عشر من - المفصل، وسورتين من آل حم»
> One among the people said: I recited all the mufassal surahs during the night. 'Abdullah said: (You must have recited them) like the (recitation) of poetry. I heard (the Holy Prophet) combining (the sarahs) and I remember the combinations which the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) made In the recitation (of surahs). These were constituted of eighteen mufassal surahs and two surahs (commencing with) Ha-Mim.
> (Source of the translation: The version from Sahih Muslim on sunnah.com)

In fact Muslim complied it in [his Sahih](https://sunnah.com/muslim:822d). While al-Bukhari mainly only compiled this addition in [his Sahih](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5043) via abu an-Nu'maan instead of Shabyan ibn Farukh.

**The narrators**

- Muhammad ibn 'Ali محمد بن علي القطبي: As stated above the database gave 6 results unfortunately the matching or intersection between the teachers of ibn as-Sunni and the Students of Bishr ibn Musa al-Asadi al-Baghdadi gave a rather *unknown* narrator: Muhammad ibn 'Ali al-Qutby (See [here](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/52656/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A)).
- Bishr ibn Musa  بشر بن موسى الأسدي: (born 190 a.H. - apparently died 288 a.H. due to a-Dhahabi's statement: he lived 98 years) most scholars like a-Daraqotni and a-Dhahabi himself regarded him as trustworthy, Ahmad wrote him a letter of recommendation to introduce him to al-Hamidy (See in a-Dahabi's [Siyar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2568&bk_no=60&flag=1) and in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/12862/%D8%A8%D9%90%D8%B4%D9%92%D8%B1%D9%8F%20%D8%A8%D9%92%D9%86%D9%8F%20%D9%85%D9%8F%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%8E%D9%89)). He was indeed a teacher of Yahya ibn IShaaq al-Bajly or as-Saylahyny.
- Yahya ibn Ishaaq as-Saylahyny يحيى بن إسحاق البجلي (also al-Bajly, as-Saylahuny, as-Saalhyny) : (died in Baghdad 210 a.H.) a-Dhahabi said in his Tareekh (biography [#402 here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31912/7472#p1)): as-Saalihyn was a village in Baghdad. He is regarded as rather trustworthy: ibn Sa'ad qualified him as trustworthy and Ahmad once said he is trustworthy another time sadooq. Ibn Hajar and ibn Ma'yn qualified him as sadooq according [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/8215/%D9%8A%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%89-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%82). He indeed was a student of Mahdi ibn Maymoon. Abu Dawod narrated a strange narration via him in his al-Maraseel at which a-Dahabi pointed in his Tareekh.
- Mahdi ibn Maymoon مهدي بن ميمون الأزدي: (died 171 a.H. or 172a.H. according ibn Sa'ad) he is mainly regarded as trustworthy: A-Dhahabi called him trustworthy and hafidh in his [Siyar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1286&bk_no=60&flag=1) he was a student of the qaari' Ya'aqob al-Hadrami from Basra. Waasil ibn Hiyyan al-Ahdab was among his teachers (see also in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/7701/%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86)).
- Waasil al-Ahdab واصل بن حيان الأحدب: (died 120 a.H.) He is mainly regarded as a trustworthy narrator.  Al-Bukhari mainly reported from him via Mahdi ibn Maymoon, a-Thawry and Sho'abah. He is regarded as trustworthy by ibn Ma'yin, an-Nasa-i and abu Dawod; as sadooq and hassan al-Hadith by abu Hathim. Al Mizi confirms his narration from Shaqeeq abu Salamah also known as abu Wa'il in his Tahdeed al-Kamaal biography [#6662](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3722/16502#p1) and see also in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/8118/%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%86).
- abu Wa'il أبو وائل شقيق بن سلمة الأسدي: (1 a.H. - 82 a.H. according [Arabic wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%82_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A9) however the reports in other books are a bit confusing) is an early Tabi'y who was born during the lifetime of the prophet (), but didn't meet him, some even indicate that he even became a Muslim in this time. It is said -according a-Dhahabi's Syiar- that he reported from abu Bakr: Some statements however hardly fit for example he said to al-'A'amash that if he had died in the [battle of Buzakha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Buzakha) he would end up in hell, but this happened after the death of the prophet(), further here some reports say that he was 11 others reported him saying he was 21 at the time. So the safest is to say that he was born during the lifetime of the prophet () and didn't meet him. He is regarded as trustworthy. See also in a-Dahabi's [Siyar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=502&bk_no=60&flag=1), in al-Mizi's Tahdeed al-Kamal biography [#2767](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3722/6356#p1) and in the database. Ibn Sa'ad qualified him as trustworthy with many narratives, ibn Ma'yn said he is trustworthy and not of the kind one asks (doubts) about, Ibn Hathim added that he was not practicing tadlees, ibn 'Abd al_Barr even pretended that there's a consensus on him being trustworthy. He is claimed to be the most knowledgeable among the people of al-Kufa about ibn Masu'd's hadith.

So except with the teacher of ibn as-Sunni, who seems unknown (but could be reliable) we have a reliable chain of transmission here.

### Analysis of the du'a: Asbahna wa asbaha al-Mulku li-Llaah ...

**Hadith including the full narrator chain in ibn as-Sunni's book**

> 38 - حدثنا الحسين بن محمد، أخبرنا أبو داود، حدثنا أبو قتادة، حدثنا أبو الورقاء، حدثنا **ابن أبي أوفى**، قال: كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إذا أصبح قال: «أصبحنا وأصبح الملك لله عز وجل، والحمد لله، والكبرياء والعظمة لله، والخلق والأمر، والليل والنهار وما سكن فيهما لله عز وجل، اللهم اجعل أول هذا النهار صلاحا، وأوسطه نجاحا، وآخره فلاحا، يا أرحم الراحمين» ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13132/68#p1))
> We were informed by al-Hussayn ibn Muhammad from abu Dawod from abu Qatadah from abu al-Warqaa' from ibn abu 'Awfa who said: the Messenger of Allah Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him used to say in the morning: "We have reached the morning, and in the morning the dominion belongs to Allah; praise is due to Allah; majesty and might belong to Allah; the creation, the command, night and day and what is at rest by night and day belong to Allah. O Allah, make the beginning of this day uprightness, its middle success, and its end attainment, O most merciful among those who show mercy."

See also in [Mishkat al-Masabih](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2414), [here #296](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13016/304) in at-Tabarani's a-Du'aa', [here #531](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13170/644) in 'Abd ibn Humayd's عبد بن حميد الكشي Musnad (which is the one root of the narration on which ibn Hajar narrated it from his teachers) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/33169) in Mosannaf ibn abi Shaybah with a different chain and slightly different wording.

Again at least 6 teachers of ibn as-Sunni could be called al-Hussayn ibn Muhammad. However this time the majority of them are reliable hadith transmitters.

- Al-Hussayn ibn Muhammad al-'Abdy الحسين بن محمد العبدي: Who studied and thought al-Bukhari and other known authors of hadith compilations. (died 289 a.H., trustworthy).
- Al-Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn Sa'id al-Bazaz (known as ibn al-Mutabiqi) الحسين بن محمد بن سعيد البزاز: A teacher of a-Daraqotni. (died 328 a.H., trustworthy)
- Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn Mus'ab ibn Ruzyq حسين بن محمد بن مصعب بن رزيق (known as abu 'Ali and also referred to as al-Bajli, as-Sinji or al-Maroozi): who was a teacher of ibn Hebban. (died 316 a.H., trustworthy)
- Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn Mawdood ibn Hammaad al Harani or al-Jazari حسين بن محمد بن مودود بن حماد: a teacher of ibn Hebban and ibn 'Ady and student of abu Dawood. (born after 220 a.H. and died 318 a.H., trustworthy)
- Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn Bakhtawayh ibn 'Ali ad-Daynuri الحسين بن محمد بن بختويه بن علي الدينوري: Imam a-Daraqotni regarded him as trustworthy (conclusion:he must have met him, a-Daraqotni was born 306 a.H.), the database qualifies him as unknown.
- Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn a-Dahhaak or al-Farisi or al-Masri (abu 'Abduallah) حسين بن محمد بن الضحاك: Is marked as unknown by the database and has at least four students and teachers teachers in it.

**Some scholarly qualification and analysis**

Imam an-Nawawi remained silent on the qualification of this hadith in his al-Adhkar (see here [#226](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1956/83)). While al-Arnaoot qualified the isnaad as da'if in his commentary.

Bashir Muhammad 'Uyon a contemporary commentator on the book of ibn as-Sunni  added the following footnote (View 'Amal al-Yawm wal-Laylah page 22):
[image]
So this hadith was also reported by at-Tabarani and beside abu al-Warqaa' which al-Haythami declared as matrook (rejected) in his al-Majma', there's abu Qatadah which al-Albani regarded as matrook too and which lead to the grading of the hadith as da'if jiddan.

Ibn Hajar mentioned the hadith in his Nata'ij al-Afkar Volume 2 pages 402-403 and declared it as gharib and it's sanad as da'if. He identified the weakness in Fa'id or Fayid also known as Fa'idah ibn al-Warqaa' who's the son of 'Abdurrahman al-'Attar so he is also referred to as Fayid ibn 'Abd ar-Rahmaan al-Madany فايد بن عبد الرحمن المدني and there's agreement on his weakness among scholars (see in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/6379/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%86)). Ibn Hajar quoted that imam Ahmad regarded him as matrook (rejected), al-Bukhari munkar al-Hadith, abu Hathim ar-Razi stated his hadith is baatil (~fabricated). However ibn 'Ady in his al-Kamil concluded despite the negative grading that his hadith can be written (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12579/3354#p1) and the preceding pages). Note that ibn 'Ady quoted two of his narrations one of them is our hadith in question.

**The narrators**

This chain of transmission seems tough to check, because of many ambiguities. If we assume that abu Dawod refers to the known author of the Sunan and Maraaseel I still would have an issue on identifying abu Qatadah without the input of al-Albani who identified him as 'Abdullah ibn Waaqid al-Haraani.

- Hussayn ibn Muhammad ibn Mawdood ibn Hammaad al Harani or al-Jazari (also known as abu 'Urubah أَبُو عَرُوبَةَ) حسين بن محمد بن مودود بن حماد: (born after 220 a.H. and died 318 a.H. according a-Dhahabi's [Siyar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2996&bk_no=60&flag=1)) a teacher of ibn Hebban the author of the Sahih and many books on hadith narrators, at-Tabbarani the author of several books and hadith compilations, abu Ahmad al-Hakim from Nishapure the author of al-Kuna الْكُنَى and ibn 'Ady the author of al-Kamil fi a-Do'afaa'. And he was a student of abu Dawood and Ishaaq ibn Rahawayh. . See also in [the database](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/15382/%D8%A3%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%8F%D9%88%20%D8%B9%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%8F%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%8E).
- Abu Dawod as-Sijistani and also al-Azadi (Sulayman ibn la-Asha'ath سليمان بن الأشعث)  أبو داود السجستاني: (202 a.H. - 207 a.H. according [Arabic wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%AF)) he is the known author of several books among them his Sunan -which is stated to be the first book of this kind- which he presented imam Ahmad, his Maraseel, An-Nasikh wal-Mansukh (qur'an sciences) he also has a book of questions he asked imam Ahmad one about narrators etc.. See also in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/3567/%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%AB-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%82-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86).
- Abu Qatadah (who is 'Abdullah ibn Waqid al-Haraani) عبد الله بن واقد الحراني: (died 207 or 210 a.H.) and he was accused for fabrication. However it is more likely that he confused and mixed in his age, as imam Ahmad and also ibn Ma'yn said -at least in one of their grading reported about him- about him nice words. He seems to have been faithful worshiper, but had a bad memory and therefore he was not much reliable as a hadith narrator. He was a student of the scholars Sufyan a-Thawry, al-'Awza'iy, abu Hanifa and al-Layth ibn Sa'ad whom all had an own madhhab which was followed by many Muslims beside Fayd ibn Abd ar-Rahmaan al-Madani also known as abu al-Warqaa'. A-Dhahabi commented one of his narrations which he reported via Sufyan a-Thawry on the incident of al-Isra', and came in first place stated that he cannot imagine that the strangeness of the report can be originated by him until he found out that the same report was compiled by at-Tabarani through him and came to the conclusion that abu Qatadah was the issue of this hadith. See his biography in [Kitab al-Matrookyn #560](https://al-maktaba.org/book/5834/317) of ibn Hebban and also in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/5141/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AF). Note that abu Dawod must have met him when he started studying.
- Abu al-Warqaa' أبو الورقاء is fayid or faidah ibn 'Abd ar-Rahmaan al-Madyni  فايد بن عبد الرحمن المدني: (died 159 a.H.): As stated above he is in best case da'if, but the main view about him is that he rather is matrook. Abu 'Abdullah al-Hakim said: he reported on the authorithy of 'Abdullah ibn Awfa fabricated ahadith. Ibn abi Hathim reported form abu Zura'ha and his father that none -whohas knowledge in this science- cares about his hadith and also his father saying: He is dhaahib al-Hadith, his hadith is not to be written,  and further it was reported from abu Hathim ar-Razi that his ahadith from ibn Awfa are false (baatil) which has no origin, it doesn't look like the words (hadith) of abu Awfa, and if a man swore about him that all his hadith is nothing but lies it would be hard to refute (see in ibn Hajar's [Tahdeed at-Tahdeeb #474](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3310/3746)). See also in [the database](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/6379/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%86).

So this hadith has a severe issue in the chain of transmission which is abu al-Warqaa' whom's reports on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn Awfa are regarded as fabrication by many scholars, even the rather lenient al-Hakim from Nishapure (author of al-Mustadrak) says so. Beside this Qatadah is mainyl accused for his bad memory and issues in his reports which make the two an issue for this narrator chain. It is however understandable that a young student as abu Dawod was, would consult a known faithful scholar and worshiper as abu Qatadah was described as to learn hadith after excelling the qur'an.

Nevertheless the first part of it:

> أَصْبَحْنَا وَأَصْبَحَ الْمُلْكُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ
> We have reached the morning, and in the morning the dominion belongs to Allah, the Lord of the universe.

has a backup in the Sahih as one may read in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2723b). And in a hadith graded as da'if by al-Albani in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5084).

### Analysis of the du'a: Allahumma ij'all khayra 'Umury aakhirahu ...

**Hadith including the full narrator chain in ibn as-Sunni's book**

In the given case I'll rely mainly on this article [on alukah](https://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/79274/) -in which the author claims this hadith to be da'if jiddan (very weak)-, but I'll add the (correct) sources (and additional sources if available in the same reference) which were referred to.

> 121 - حدثني عمر بن سهل، حدثنا نجيح بن إبراهيم، حدثنا إبراهيم بن محمد بن ميمون، حدثنا صالح بن أبي الأسود، عن عبد الملك النخعي، عن ابن جدعان، عن **أنس بن مالك**، رضي الله عنه قال: كان مقامي بين كتفي النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم حتى قبض، فكان يقول إذا انصرف من الصلاة: «اللهم اجعل خير عمري آخره، وخير عملي خواتمه، واجعل خير أيامي يوم ألقاك» ([Source](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13132/230#p1))
> I was informed by 'Umar ibn Sahl, from Najeeh ibn Ibraheem, from Ibraheem ibn Muhammad ibn Maymoon, from Saalih ibn abi al-Aswad, from 'abd(u) al-Malik an-Nakha'iy, from ibn Jud'aan from Anas ibn Malik may Allah be pleased with him said: My placement was between the shoulders of the Prophet, may Allah's prayers and blessing be upon him, until he died.
> He used to say when he finished the prayer: "O Allah, make the best of my lifespan the last of it, and the best of my deeds the last of them, and make the best of my days the day I meet You"

The hadith also appears in at-Tabarani's al-Awsat in [#9448](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/9859) (as a part of a du'a of an 'A'arabi (bedouin) which the prophet() heard, with the exact wording of ibn as-Sunni) and [#9411](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/9819) -with a deviation in the wording- (this was the root of ibn Hajar in Nata'ij al-Fikr) and (Isma'il ibn Muhammad) al-Asbahani's at-Targheeb wa at-Tarheeb [#1317](https://al-maktaba.org/book/26884/1323) (not 317 as in alukah) who rather attributed the statement to abu Bakr.

**Some scholarly qualification and analysis**

Imam an-Nawawi remained silent on the qualification of this hadith in his al-Adhkar (see here #[196](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1956/75)). While al-Arnaoot qualified the isnaad as da'if in his commentary.

The above mentioned article mentions three issues in the hadith:

- Saalih ibn abi al-Aswad, which is declared as not trustworthy by scholars like ibn Hajar and a-Dhahabi.
- 'Abdu al-Malik an-Nakha'iy who is matruk. He is also known as abu Malik.
- 'Ali ibn Zayd ibn Jud'aan who is da'if due to his bad memorization abilities.

At-Tabarani commented on #9411 saying none reported it from abu al-Muhajjal except with 'Abdu al-Malik ibn al-Hussayn and it was only reported -this way- by abu Bakr ibn abu an-Naddr.
Ibn Hajar commented the narrator chain of at-Tabarani that abu Bakr ibn abu an-Naddr and his father abu an-Naddr are known teachers of imam Muslim while his grandfather Hashim ibn al-Qasim هاشم بن القاسم is a man of the two sahihs, as for abu al-Muhajjal, ibn Ma'iyn accepted him as trustworthy, and the teacher of at-Tabarani Haytham ibn Khalaf is also trustworthy and so is the son of Anas's brother (his name is Hafs حفص), the only remaining narrator who is abu Malik an-Nakha'iy and he is weak by agreement and there's a difference of opinion about his narration from his teacher (referring to 'Abdu al-Malik ibn al-Hussayn). I hope this is the correct translation of his statement -if not please anyone guide me-:

> وقد اختلف عليه في شيخه

As al-Qassim ibn al_Waleed القاسم بن الوليد  didn't even meet Anas ibn Malik () the version from the book of al-Asbahani has a disconnected chain of transmission.

At-Tabarni further commented the version of #9448 saying none has reported this via Humayd حميد except with Hushaym and none from Hushaym  هشيم -with the given wording- except with al-'Adhramiy الأذرمي.

**The narrators**

'Umar ibn Sahl عمر بن سهل الدينوري: (died 307 a.H.) is regarded as hafidh and trustworthy as stated in a-Dhahabi's [Siyar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3214&bk_no=60&flag=1) and in [the database](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/25203/%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%87%D9%84).

Najeeh ibn Ibraheem نجيح بن إبراهيم الكرماني: (died 286 a.H.) was a Qadi in al-Kufa, ibn Hebban mentioned him in his a-Thiqaat however he added the comment that he was reporting strangeness's, ibn Hajar  qualified him as *da'if* in Lissan al-Mizaan [#525](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12063/2935#p1), see also in the [database](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/32656/%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF).

Ibraheemn ibn Muhamad ibn Maymoon إبراهيم بن محمد بن ميمون: Is regarded as *munkar al-Hadith* as stated in [the database](https://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/11828/%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86). Both a-Dhahabi and ibn Hajar said that he is a shi'a scholar see in Lissan al-Mizan [#318 here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12063/108#p1). Ibn Hajar further said his teacher didn't regard this person as trustworthy and reported from at-Tusi's (a shi'a hadith scholar) book a statement of Ibrahim ibn abu Bakr ibn abi Shaybah quoting his uncle 'Uthman ibn abi Shaybah a praise fo two shi'a narrators of which Ibraheem ibn Muhammad ibn  Maymoon al-Kindi was one of, he also quoted that ibn Hebban quoted him in his a-Thiqaat and said he is a Kindi.

Saalibn abi al-Aswad  صالح بن أبي الأسود الليثي: is also regarded as da'if because of his bad hadith transmission and rather

'Abdulmalik an-Nakha'iy عبد الملك النخعي:

Ibn Jad'aan ابن جدعان:

Comment: Which means that when Ibn Hajar states that the first hadith has a *sahih isnad*, that he provided evidence about the narrators to classify it in this regard. Or is there a further objection?

Comment: @harmer97 no he only quoted his version with his chain and gave a qualification. I guess this could be a/the version from Sahih ibn Hebban.

Comment: Would be nice to see this hadith in the answer. I myself have not found yet anything about the other two ahadith.

Comment: Is this the mauquf hadith from Ibn Masud narrated in Sahih Ibn Hibban (2607) https://dorar.net/hadith/sharh/26322?

Comment: https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/3837#p1 | I also found it on Al-Maktaba, but I think the wording is a bit different compared to Ibn as-Sunni.

Comment: @harmer97 I've found it and added/referred to it too as you may have seen.

Comment: So, in Latin form: *Elhamdulillahil-ladhi a-qalana yawmana hadha wa lam yuhlikna bi-dhunubina* (I do not want to use google translate because it is slightly inaccurate) | The commentator also added Ibn Abi Shaybah (2/272-3) as a narration and Al-Baghawi (908) and I think on the authority of Abu Hurayrah; maybe you can add this as well (perhaps there are further additions)

Comment: @harmer97 nope that part of the comment is referring to an incomplete comment of the preceding hadith. I thought the same, but checked the context of the sentence and it made more sense if we regard it related to a statement before in which al-Baghawi used the same chain as ibn Shaybah. However it appears in the wording of ibn Hebban in Sahih Muslim and partly in Sahih al-Bukhari.

Comment: It is the same dhikr in Sahih Muslim that appears in Sahih Ibn Hibban. The translation is then on Sunnah.com.

Comment: Yes the difference is the intermediate as ibn Hebban only met scholars from Muslim's era he heard it from abu Ya'la from Shayban ibn Farrukh. The footnote/commentary says وأخرجه مسلم (822) (278) في صلاة المسافرين: باب ترتيل القراءة واجتناب الهذ، عن شيبان بن فروخ، بهذا الإسناد.

Comment: So, to understand it fully, the hadith of Ibn as-Sunni is not authentic, only the two we discussed now?

Comment: @harmer97 well the two discussed are authentic, that of ibn as-Sunni is as well. However the content is a bit different in order and wording. Assuming the qualification of Muslim about his teacher is correct, the wording of Muslim and ibn Hebban would be more accurate. As even al-Bukhari compiled paraphrased hadith in dome cases, while Muslim was more accurate in this context, al-Bukhari was more strict in the choice of narrators.

Comment: Is it not interesting that An-Nawawi did not include 'Al-Mahdi said': "And I think he said: *He did not torment us with fire*" as an addition to this Dhikr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130075/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-harmer97).